# Is there any way in VS 2013 to have Git Settings by repo/solution? (and not only one global)

Tags: git, visual-studio

I am using VS 2013 with built in Git support. I would like to  participate  in multiple projects in multiple git servers like

- bitbucket.org
- github.com
- anyhost.visualstudio.com (using git)
- otherhost.visualstudio.com (using git)

In the VS 2013 Git Setting page of the Team Explorer, there is a 'User Name' and 'Email Address' setting. However these settings are global. In the different servers listed above I have different user names (and possibly different emails). Also it is possible that two different MS subscriptions in *.visualstudio.com (like anyhost.visualstudio.com, and otherhost.visualstudio.com) I have different logins, and that's why different email adresses. If the email metainfo in the commit does not match with the used login, then the commit history will not recognize me, no avatar, etc.

Is there any way to set the user name and email address meta info in solution/repo bases instead of having one global setting? Unless having this, I must change the username and email settings always when I open a new solution belonging to an other server.

(Please note: I am not talking about authentication. That's OK, VS remembers or asks for the credentials correctly.)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's quite easy to do from the commandline. Visual Studio will respect this setting. http://stackoverflow.com/a/18181510/736079

Comment: Thanks good point. Actually editing .git/config solves my problem, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220416/can-i-specify-multiple-users-for-myself-in-gitconfig

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to jessehouwing and some further research:

The simplest way to go and edit .git/config in every repo and place these 3 lines: (or use git config to do this for you)

```
[user]  
    name = your name
    email = your.name@anyhost.com
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. VS2013 was not configuring it and now i added above settings manually into config and it worked for me